# How to insert a value into a doubly linked list using C

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I am just trying to insert a value to a sorted doubly linked list in C.
When I print it out using the following it never shows the newly created node. I created a new node and then set the values and then update the prev and next pointers for the new node and the node that was in front of it. I am sure it has something to do with pass by reference and would like to understand why?

```
struct NodeType {
int data;
struct NodeType * prev;
struct NodeType * next;
}*head, *last;

void insert_double(int key);
void displayList();
void find_node(int key);


int main()
{

head = NULL;
last = NULL;
/* Create a list with one as value and set as head */
head = (struct NodeType *)malloc(sizeof(struct NodeType));
head->data = 3;
head->prev = NULL;
head->next = NULL;
last = head;

int value=1;

insert_double(value);
printf("0\n");
displayList();
printf("1\n");
value=2;
printf("2\n");
find_node(value);
printf("3\n");
displayList();

return 0;

}

void displayList()
{
struct NodeType * temp;
int n = 1;

if(head == NULL)
{
    printf("List is empty.\n");
}
else
{
    temp = head;
    printf("DATA IN THE LIST:\n");

    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("DATA of %d node = %d\n", n, temp->data);

        n++;

        /* Move the current pointer to next node */
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
}

void find_node(int key)
{
struct NodeType * temp;
struct NodeType * newnode;
newnode->data=key;
 if(head == NULL){
    printf("No nodes");
}
else{
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if((temp->data)< key){
            newnode->prev=temp->prev;
            newnode->next=temp;
            temp->prev=newnode;
            break;
        }
        else{
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }

}


}

void insert_double(int key)
{
struct NodeType * newnode;

if(head == NULL)
{
    printf("Empty!\n");
}
else
{
    newnode = (struct NodeType *)malloc(sizeof(struct NodeType));

    newnode->data = key;
    newnode->next = head; // Point to next node which is currently head
    newnode->prev = NULL; // Previous node of first node is NULL

    /* Link previous address field of head with newnode */
    head->prev = newnode;

    /* Make the new node as head node */
    head = newnode;

}
}
```

Comment: In find_node() new_node is being used (via new_node->data = key) before new_node is assigned a value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your insertion function works fine, as does `displayList`.

However, the program has undefined behavior in the `find_node` function:

```
void find_node(int key)
{
    struct NodeType * temp;
    struct NodeType * newnode;
    newnode->data=key;            //<-- BOOM! (writing to uninitialized pointer)

    if(head == NULL){
        printf("No nodes");
    }
    else{
        temp=head;
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            if((temp->data)< key){
                newnode->prev=temp->prev; //<-- BOOM!
                newnode->next=temp;       //<-- BOOM!
                temp->prev=newnode;
                break;
            }
            else{
                temp=temp->next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve there.  If this really is a *find* function, it should not be attempting to perform operations on nodes or copy any data.

All you really need is something like this:

```
struct NodeType* find_node(int key)
{
    for(struct NodeType* temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
    {
        if (temp->data == key)
            return temp;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically correct. You are just missing two important edge cases when dealing with linked list. First is when you are using `find_node` to insert some value, but it's gonna be add in the beginning in the list. In this case your newly created node becomes a new head of a list so you have to update a `head` variable. The second edge case is kind of opposite, it happens when you are inserting the new node to the end of the list. Then it becomes an end of a list so you need to update `tail`.

Missing those two edge cases happens a lot when first working with the linked lists, so don't worry. I think pretty much everybody who worked with linked list made these mistakes in the beginning of his journey.

Moreover you are using the uninitialized pointer to the `NodeType` structure in `find_node`:

`struct NodeType * newnode;`

it should be:

`struct NodeType * newnode = (struct NodeType *)malloc(sizeof(struct NodeType));`

Comment: Fair enough I didn't really name the method correct. I was really looking to insert to a sorted doubly linked list. Based on your comments, thanks to both of you I had an issue with covering the edge cases and the uninitialized pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both of you. Here is the solution I came up based on both of your input:

```
void insert_sorted_node(int key){
struct NodeType * temp = (struct NodeType *)malloc(sizeof(struct NodeType));
struct NodeType * newnode = (struct NodeType *)malloc(sizeof(struct NodeType));
newnode->data=key;
/* no nodes at all*/
/* insert_sorted_node(value) can't start empty list, need to fix */
 if(head == NULL){
    printf("head =null");
    temp = head;
    head->data=key;
    head->prev=NULL;
    head->next=NULL;
    last = head;
}
else{
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\ndata = %d\nkey = %d\n", temp->data, key);

        /* key is new head 
            1) check if key < head->data

        */
        if(key<head->data)
        {
            printf("\nnew head\n");
            newnode->prev = head->prev;
            newnode->next = temp;
            temp->prev = newnode;
            head = newnode;
            break;

        }

        /* key is tail 
            if temp->next = NULL
        */
        else if(temp->next == NULL)
        {
            printf("\ntail\n");
            newnode->prev = temp;
            newnode->next = NULL;
            temp->next = newnode;
            last = newnode;
            break;
        }

        /* key is middle head 
            if key > temp->data and key< temp->next->data 

        */
        else if((key>temp->data)&&(key<temp->next->data))
        {
            printf("\nmiddle\n");
            newnode->prev=temp;
            newnode->next=temp->next;
            temp->next=newnode;
            temp->next->prev=newnode;
            break;
        }


        else{
            printf("next\n");
            temp=temp->next;
        }
    }



}


 }
```